# US $ transfer from Indian NRE external account to US account

Tags: taxes, india, bank-account, international-transfer

I have a NRE External Account-US $ 50,000 Fixed deposit in Indian nationalised bank on my name with nominee as my daughter.I now want to wire transfer same to my daughter on her US Bank account.
Is there any restriction on this transaction in Indian side?

Comment: Why not ask your bank?

Answer (score 2):

As you have an NRE account, all funds in this account are freely repatriate-able  without any restriction.

Note depending on your tax status in US, you may have a gift tax obligation.